# Spring Error - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

I am quite new to Spring and Java world. I am trying to write a web app looking at petclinic application provided in the samples. However, I am hitting this roadblock since yesterday. It will be great if someone can point me in right direction. I looked up many links on google, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here is the error root cause

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
```

.
.
.

Here is my web.xml in WEB-INF

```
<display-name>Game's List</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-hibernate.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gamelist</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gamelist</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the applicationContext-hibernate.xml

```
<!-- ========================= RESOURCE DEFINITIONS ========================= -->

<!-- import the dataSource definition -->
<import resource="applicationContext-dataSource.xml"/>
<!-- Configurer that replaces ${...} placeholders with values from a properties file -->
<!-- (in this case, Hibernate-related settings for the sessionFactory definition below) -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:mappingResources="gamelist-hibernate.xml">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="merge">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- central data access object: Hibernate implementation -->
<bean id="gameDataStore" class="com.gamelist.datastore.GameItemDataStore"/>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

<!-- ========================= BUSINESS OBJECT DEFINITIONS ========================= -->

<!--
    Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes:
    Spring's @Required and @Autowired, as well as JSR 250's @Resource.
-->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!--
    Instruct Spring to perform declarative transaction management
    automatically on annotated classes.
-->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<!--
    Exporter that exposes the Hibernate statistics service via JMX. Autodetects the
    service MBean, using its bean name as JMX object name.
-->
<context:mbean-export/>
```

This is gamelist-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gamelist"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

This is the controller class

```
    public class GameLibraryController {

    private IDataStore gameDataStore;

    @Autowired
    public GameLibraryController(GameItemDataStore gameDataStore){
        this.gameDataStore = gameDataStore;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addGame")
    public String addNewGame(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("gameItem",new GameItem());
        return "library/addgameform";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addGameSubmit")
    public void add(@ModelAttribute GameItem gameItem,BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
        this.gameDataStore.add(gameItem);
        status.setComplete();
    }
}
```

This is the hibernate implementation class GameItemDataStore

```
  @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class GameItemDataStore implements IDataStore{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public GameItemDataStore(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void add(BaseItem newGame){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(newGame);
    }
}
```

This is the IDataStore interface

```
 public interface IDataStore {

    public void add(BaseItem newGame);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full exception stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid any confusion, I am going to assume the configuration you mentioned in the question, and start from there. (Ignoring the changes you may have tried after reading the comments on your question)

First a little background:

1. There are two contexts at play in a Spring MVC application. The `applicationContext` which is more accurately referred to as the `ROOT WebApplicationContext`, which is meant to be available to all `Servlet` level spring contexts, through an integration with the Servlet Container's lifecycle implementation. The second type of context is loaded for each `DispatcherServlet` configured in the `web.xml` lets call it `ServletApplicationContext`
2. Now, when the container starts, the Root application context is loaded
3. When the Servlet is loaded, the Servlet Application Context is loaded. At this point, beans from the Root Application Context are available to the Servlet Application Context.
4. IF, you do end up loading the same bean definitions in both the contexts, its like overriding beans in the Servlet Context. Very inefficient to load duplicate beans, and can cause weird errors if you are relying on the same instance being available in all context. But, for simple cases like a single servlet deployment, this should not cause your application to break at startup, spring will deal with this.

Now getting to what's wrong with your configuration:

1. There is no `ContextLoaderListener` configured in your `web.xml`. Without a ContextLoaderListener, the ROOT application context is NOT loaded. So none of the beans from `/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-hibernate.xml` are loaded.
2. When your servlet kicks up, it loads the beans from `gamelist-servlet.xml`, and cannot locate a `sessionFactory` bean, because the ROOT Web Application Context was never loaded~!
3. To confirm this, for a test, comment out all bean definitions from the two context files, just keep empty `<beans></beans>` tags in them. Start your server, you'll see a log statement at the end that says something like `no ROOT Web Application Context found, configure ContextLoaderListener in web.xml`

And the fix:

1. Add the `ContextLoaderListener` to your `web.xml`
2. You may choose to continue your configuration as you have it now, or follow the advice given in earlier comments and include only MVC related definitions in the servlet context and all else in the ROOT application context.
3. Another, simpler option would be to simply have an empty application context xml for the ROOT Web Application Context, and configure all beans in the servlet context. This is not correct from a `purist` design point of view, but a practical simple solution, provided you plan on having a single servlet application.

Sorry for the looong description, but I felt some explanation was mandated. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

```
<bean id="gameDataStore" class="com.gamelist.datastore.GameItemDataStore"/>
```

which you won't need because of `@Repository` on your class and

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

which you have twice. Then add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" />
```

where `com.your.package` is a top level package that contains the `GameItemDataStore` class.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is a typo.
However, I tried what you said. I added component-scan base-package to com.gamelist which is top level even to applicationContext-hibernate.xml (although is it required since it is included in the gamelist-servelet.xml??) And it still gives me that error.
My IDE (IntelliJ) for some reason does not show any error. This error pops only when I run it.

Comment: Don't put the controller and repository classes in the same package. Your servlet context should scan a different package then your application context. Otherwise you would get stuck with many beans of the same type.

Comment: okay. That makes sense. I changed the base package in gamelist-servlet to point to package where controllers reside.
And in applicationContext-hibernate I changed the base-package to 
1. com.gamelist (Top level)
2. com.gamelist.datastore (where hibernate implementation resides)

In both the cases I am getting this error now
    NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.gamelist.datastore.GameItemDataStore]
Another question, in previous case when servlet context & application context were same, why did it not find sessionfactory? I had only one bean of sessionfactory?

Comment: I think you (and your application) are mixing contexts. The ApplicationContext is the root context. It is "global". The `gamelist` context is the `DispatcherServlet` context. It has its own beans that are only relevant (and visible) to that context, ie. beans declared in the ApplicationContext cannot reference (inject) them. When you declare component scan packages, the root context should scan a package containing application wide component, while the servlet component scan should scan servlet relevant component.